# SPSS Python syntax keywords formatting

Tags: python, spss

Inside an SPSS syntax file, the python code is written between `begin program.` and `end program.` commands. However, the SPS syntax editor only highlights the SPSS-specific keywords, so all the python code is just black text on white background; no IDLE-style highlights.

Is there a syntax editor which highlights both SPSS keywords and the python code...?

Answer (score 1):

[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.5.1.html) will highlight Python but doesn't recognize SPSS syntax. On the other hand, it allows you to define your own language, so with some amount of work (teach it your common commands and functions) you might be able to reach what you need.
There are [tools](https://github.com/Remix4Dev/npp-spss) to use Notepad++ as an SPSS syntax editor - that may be a good shortcut for you, though I never tried this so I can't recommend it.